# How to remove border from last-child?

Tags: html, css

So i have this demo https://fiddle.jshell.net/nx4s6jsd/ where i have that html structure. I want to remove broder-bottom from last child but i dont know how. I tried with

```
.product:last-child{
   border-bottom:none:
}
```

but its not working .Any suggestion?

```
<div class="checkout">
                            <div class="checkout_title"><span>Vasa narudzba</span></div>
                                <div class="product custom_form_title order_product_list">  
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 no-padding-right">
                                            <div class="product_image">
                                                <img src="assets/img/product1_small.png" class="img-responsive" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                                            <div class="product_box">
                                                <div class="product_title">
                                                    <span>Product title</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="product_description">
                                                    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. IntegeLorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                                <div class="product custom_form_title order_product_list">  
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 no-padding-right">
                                            <div class="product_image">
                                                <img src="assets/img/product1_small.png" class="img-responsive" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                                            <div class="product_box">
                                                <div class="product_title">
                                                    <span>Product title</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="product_description">
                                                    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. IntegeLorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="total custom_form_title order_list">
                                            <span class="left-title">Cijena bez PDV-a</span><span class="right-title">0,000.00 KM</span>
                                            <span class="left-title">PDV(17%)</span><span class="right-title right">0,000.00 KM</span>
                                            <span class="left-title">Postarina</span><span class="right-title right">0,000.00 KM</span>
                                            <span class="left-title">Total cijena</span><span class="right-title right">0,000.00 KM</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to wrap `.product` with in div, the problem is right now in you code `.product` is not last-child of parent div so check my code snippet

```css
.black_line{
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #24282f;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.finish_button{
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.finish_button a{
   padding: 12px 45px;
}
.right{
    float: right;
}
.order_list{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-top:1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.order_product_list{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
.order_product_list:last-child{border: 0;}
```

```html
<div class="checkout">
                            <div class="checkout_title"><span>Vasa narudzba</span></div>
  <div class="product-holder">
                                <div class="product custom_form_title order_product_list">  
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 no-padding-right">
                                            <div class="product_image">
                                                <img src="assets/img/product1_small.png" class="img-responsive" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                                            <div class="product_box">
                                                <div class="product_title">
                                                    <span>Product title</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="product_description">
                                                    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. IntegeLorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                                <div class="product custom_form_title order_product_list">  
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 no-padding-right">
                                            <div class="product_image">
                                                <img src="assets/img/product1_small.png" class="img-responsive" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                                            <div class="product_box">
                                                <div class="product_title">
                                                    <span>Product title</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="product_description">
                                                    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. IntegeLorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div></div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="total custom_form_title order_list">
                                            <span class="left-title">Cijena bez PDV-a</span><span class="right-title">0,000.00 KM</span>
                                            <span class="left-title">PDV(17%)</span><span class="right-title right">0,000.00 KM</span>
                                            <span class="left-title">Postarina</span><span class="right-title right">0,000.00 KM</span>
                                            <span class="left-title">Total cijena</span><span class="right-title right">0,000.00 KM</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: yeah...thats it..tnx :) i will accept your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `nth-child(3)` and it will remove the border, like this:

```
.product:nth-child(3){
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

If you inspect your code you will see that after last `.product` div there is another div, so the `:last` pseudo selector won't select anything

> The last-child selector is used to select the last child element of a
>   parent. It cannot be used to select the last child element with a
>   specific class under a given parent element.

Better approach would be to wrap all the `.product` items in another container and then apply `.product:last-child` selector

Comment: It only styles the third child, what if he has more products to show?

Comment: yes, but I pointed out the problem and confusion using last-child selector

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry. Just remove style "**border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;**" from selector "**.order_product_list**".

Here is the universal solution for this type of situation. **Adjacent sibling selector (+)**.

CSS

**Add this**

```
.order_product_list + .order_product_list{
  border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```